# How to show rows with null value when doing data blending in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am connecting to the same data source twice in order to do a variance analysis in Tableau. Each cycle applies different filters. But when I did data blending on those two datasources, Tableau exclude all rows with null values in the table (those appear in the primary table but doesn't have value in the secondary table). So how to show those rows with null value?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try putting the column having the smallest level of detail as the last column in the columns, then hide it's header (this will hide the column, but its effect on the level of detail will stay there). this will enable to make the null values observable.